# Where can I download the IBM DB2 ADO.NET connector?

Tags: db2, ado.net

I have been all over their website looking. They talk about it everywhere but never have a link to a download.

And their page for opening a support ticket is broken.

So, anyone know where I can download the latest (11.5) connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download initial Version 11.5 clients and drivers](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers).
You need [IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver)](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/dispatcher.do?source=swg-idsdpds)